# Laravel Setup Isshue and composer Isshue on windows

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Not able to create new laravel project.

```
 C:\Users\Devil>composer global require "laravel/installer"
Changed current directory to C:/Users/Devil/AppData/Roaming/Composer


  [ErrorException]
  file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty


global <command-name> [<args>]...


C:\Users\Devil>laravel new blog
'laravel' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Please Help Me on this

Answer (score 1):

1 - Install composer. In case it is not yet installed here is the easiest way to [install composer on windows](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#using-the-installer)

2 - Go to your folder where you save your projects through the command line and run this command: `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project-name` . This will create a new folder `project-name`

3 - Access the `project-name` folder through the command line and run `php artisan serve`

4 - Open your browser and access `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: C:\Users\Devil\Desktop\Desktop>composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project-name


  [ErrorException]
  file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]